# Can an Android Play Store app signing key be changed only once?

Tags: android, google-play

My understanding is that even with Play App Signing, the developer can create the app signing key (and provide it to Google) and use it to sign any number of apps.  But it appears the developer can only change the signing key once during the lifetime of the app(s), true?  New keys apply only to new downloads and I guess that means an old download could never accept an update (without reinstalling the app), true?

Answer (score 0):

1. the developer can only change the signing key once during the lifetime of the app(s), true?

Yes.

[Upgrade your app signing key for new installs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdescriptions-of-keys-artifacts-and-tools%2Capp-signing-process%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-after-august%2Capp-signing-key-requirements%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-before-august):

> Each app can only have its app signing key upgraded once in its lifetime

2. New keys apply only to new downloads

True.

[Upgrade your app signing key for new installs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdescriptions-of-keys-artifacts-and-tools%2Capp-signing-process%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-after-august%2Capp-signing-key-requirements%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-before-august):

> Your new key is used to sign new installs and app updates.

3. an old download could never accept an update (without reinstalling the app), true?

No. It can accept updates with the old sign.

[Upgrade your app signing key for new installs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdescriptions-of-keys-artifacts-and-tools%2Capp-signing-process%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-after-august%2Capp-signing-key-requirements%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-before-august):

> Your legacy app signing key is still used to sign updates for users who installed your app before the key upgrade.

Comment: Thanks.  I misstated my last question, but your response answered it.